# Print out array items greater than a specific Value in Python

Tags: python, netcdf

I am trying to print out values greater than 100000 on an array MSLP
But I keep on getting this error :The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import netCDF4
from numpy import *
from netCDF4 import Dataset

ncfile= Dataset('test.nc','r')
lat  =ncfile.variables['lat'][:]
lon  =ncfile.variables['lon'][:]
time =ncfile.variables['time'][:] 
MSLP =ncfile.variables['PSL'][:]

for item in MSLP:
 if item>100000:
 print item
```

Comment: Where is `MSLP` defined? Please show your whole code.

Comment: MSLP is a Variable from a netcdf file. That is the whole code.

Comment: How many dimensions does `MSLP` have? Can you add the output of `MSLP.shape`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that. It's a three dimensional. shape(30,240,300)

Comment: @MolulaqhooaMaoyi, that's the critical piece of information. Also, please refer to my username (@SlightlyCuban) in replies, so that I get notified when the message is sent. See [comment replies](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply).

Answer (score 1):

The error gives the answer:

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

When you do `if item>100000:`, `item` is an array of truth values--not a single element.

If you want the values, you can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
MSLP[numpy.where(MSLP > 100000)]
```

Remember: prefer the numpy functions over iterating through arrays whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get all the values greater than a certain value in a list:

```
>>> array
[1, 4, 5, 7, 3, 6, 9, 3, 6]
>>> copy = list(array)
>>> array = [1, 4, 5, 7, 3, 6, 9, 3, 6]
>>> copy = []
>>> for k in array:
...     if k > x:
...             copy.append(k)
... 
>>> copy
[7, 6, 9, 6]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer but that didn't work.
All I had to do was access the array using indexes
 i.e MSLP[i][j][k]>10000, which worked out.